# IntelliJ - Delete list of previously opened projects?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way in IntelliJ IDEA to delete previously used projects? I am referring to a list on the main page when the application starts. Please look at the image.

[image]

Comment: This post is a time capsule to Intellij's UX from 12 years ago ^_^

Comment: We don't have this feature in 2024 #sad_face #thumbs_down

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`File -> Open Recent -> Clear List`

Edit: For versions of 2016+ this is no longer available. Use [This solution:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500695/7707765) File -> Open Recent -> Manage Recent Projects / Startup Dialog, ctrl+a (select multiple with ctrl+click) -> del

Edit: For versions of 2023+ the update above won't work (ctrl+a and ctrl+click)

Comment: This option has disappeard in newer versions. Why?

Comment: Option not available in 2016.2

Comment: I believe @NimChimpsky's answer is the correct one as of 2017.x

Comment: ctrl+a doesn't select all projects. Actually it does nothing.

Comment: ctrl+a does select all projects if focus is not search field but del button will remove still only 1 project from all selected projects. I wish Webstorm would have better way to manage recent & favorite projects. Some quick way from open project open another project with search option or something...

Answer (score 47):

`File -> Open Recent -> Manage Projects` .... <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove all, or hit the <kbd>X</kbd> to remove individual.

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5

Comment: Old procedure was good, this new one is bad. Why did they do this? Note that you can press X to the right as well, to remove it without right-clicking. It is easier when you have many projects.

Comment: @JohnyTex - look for Mateusz Szczepaniak's answer.  ctrl-a homboi!

Comment: Works in 2016.3 as well.

Comment: doesn't work on 2022.3.2, selecting all was still deleting one by one.

Comment: doesn't work as of  2023.1.4

Answer (score 35):

Locate [config](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181)`\options\other.xml` file and manually edit the list of recent projects inside the XML under `<component name="RecentProjectsManager">` node.

There is no way to remove individual projects from the UI. See Dan's reply otherwise.

Comment: Both ways are working. While Dan's is faster and more suitable at the moment, your suggestion is great when I need to remove just a few recent projects. Thanks.

Comment: On Mac OS, the full path of this file is /Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea12/options/other.xml

Comment: Note that you should close IntelliJ IDEA before editing this file, otherwise the list might get mangled up.

Comment: Full path on Mac is a bit different now with version 13
/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/IdealC13/options/other.xml

Comment: In idea 14 there is a separate file for this. find config\options\recentProjects.xml.

Comment: I didn't want to clear recent projects but wanted to clear other options history. This answer pointed in the right direction. If anyone else is trying to clear select dropdown history, check the XMLs in the options folder.

Comment: This is a pain - please just add a "Clear list" button.

Comment: Having the list size configurable in Settings would probably be enough, so you can set it to 1 to "clear" it and then increase again.   That said, why was the Clear-button removed?

Answer (score 7):

In MAC, ~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC14/options/recentProjects.xml is the file to easily edit the list when you do not want to lose everything. (It is for IdeaIC14).

Comment: This worked for me, for ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/options under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

In IntelliJ15, you can remove them from welcome screen, works ctrl+a and then remove all of them.

Answer (score 3):

In Idea 2019 it is located in [Idea Colder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.3/tuning-the-ide.html)\config\options\recentProjects.xml

Answer (score 3):

In idea 2022 for MAC it is located under ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2022.3/options

Answer (score 2):

idea22 on windows10 system, recent projects on the path `C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\options\recentProjects.xml`, I delete all the `<entry><\entry>` labels

Answer (score 1):

Close all projects till you reach the welcome screen. Right click on the project and choose Remove Selected from Welcome Screen. Or click on the cross arrow on the upper right corner of the selected project.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured, I am using Idea Community edition 13.1.1 and the cleanest and easiest way is to go to **File > Reopen project > Clear List**. I just stumbled upon this menu today. I always thought that is just to clear the latest projects from the view inside the IDE and just realized it is clearing the projects from the main Dialog too.

-VRS